# How do I find the smallest solution to an equation with infinitely many solutions x,y?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm solving some number theory problems, and came across one I wasn't able to solve. When I checked the solution, they got it down to the following equation (which I also found):

$10000x - 1987y = 1$

I'm meant to find the smallest integer $x$ which solves this equation. The book I'm reading just stated that "This equation has infinitely many solution and the smallest one is $x=214$" without elaborating further.

Is there any trick to find such solutions?

Answer (score 0):

All solutions are given by the *extended Euclidean algorithm* as
$$
x=214+1987k, \quad y=-1077-10000k,
$$
for $k\in \Bbb Z$.
In particular, we see, for $k=-1$ that $(x,y)=(-1773,8923)$ is also a solution. Here $x$ is certainly smaller than $214$.

On the other hand, $(x,y)=(214,-1077)$ is the solution with the smallest positive integer $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $$10000=1987(5)+65$$ so $$10000x=1987(5x)+65(x)$$ now we need to know when a multiple of $65$ is $1$ more than a multiple of $1987$ we can repeat like above ... $$1987=65(30)+37$$  and so on.